# GitHub actions remote ssh keep running although shell finished

Tags: ubuntu, github, ssh, ansible, github-actions

I am running Github actions using latest Ubuntu machine.
The step contains remote ssh with the following command:
"ansible-playbook -i inventory/hosts playbook.yml  --skip-tags network"
[Other run with remote shh shell script without ansible works fine to me]
The shell script is finished successfully after 1.5 hour (verify it on the remote host)
But GitHub actions keep running for 0.5 hour till timeout, total 2 hours (The operation was canceled)

This is the ssh command that I run through GitHub actions step:
ssh -n -x -i $PRIVATE_KEY_PATH $USER@$IP "/root/run.sh"

When I run this remote shh command from my local against remote host it works perfect to me (centos8)

Also open GitHub action community ticket on it: https://github.community/t/github-actions-remote-shell-stuck/208989

1. What can be the reason that remote shh call is not finishing on GitHub actions ?
2. Is there any limitation on GitHub actions to run ansible playbook through remote ssh ?